# Not calling event when attached with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm trying to make a function that counts how many characters left. I want to use `addEvenetListener` to listen for event types:

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');
 var tweetTxt = document.getElementById("tweettext");
 var charCount = 10;
 var tweetTxt = document.getElementById("tweettext");

 
  
 function textCounter(){
  console.log("it works");
  var count = charCount - document.getElementById("tweettext").value.length;
  
  if(count < 0){
   output.classList.add("red");
   output.classList.remove("black");
   console.log("Less than zero");
  }else{
   output.classList.add("black");
   output.classList.remove("red");
  }
  output.innerHTML = count + " characters left";
 }
 

  tweetTxt.addEventListener('onKeyDown', textCounter, false);
  tweetTxt.addEventListener('onKeyUp', textCounter, false);
  tweetTxt.addEventListener('onChange', textCounter, false);
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div>
   <textarea name="tweettext" id="tweettext">
    
   </textarea>
  </div>
  <div id="output" class="black">
   
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

For some reason, this is not working. But when I attach listeners to `<textarea>` element it works :

```js
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
 //var tweetTxt = document.getElementById("tweettext");
 var charCount = 10;
 var tweetTxt = document.getElementById("tweettext");

 
  
 function textCounter(){
  console.log("it works");
  var count = charCount - document.getElementById("tweettext").value.length;
  
  if(count < 0){
   output.classList.add("red");
   output.classList.remove("black");
   console.log("Less than zero");
  }else{
   output.classList.add("black");
   output.classList.remove("red");
  }
  output.innerHTML = count + " characters left";
 }
 

 /* tweetTxt.addEventListener('onKeyDown', textCounter, false);
  tweetTxt.addEventListener('onKeyUp', textCounter, false);
  tweetTxt.addEventListener('onChange', textCounter, false); */
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div>
   <textarea name="tweettext" id="tweettext" onKeyUp="textCounter();" onKeyDown="textCounter();" onChange="textCounter();">
    
   </textarea>
  </div>
  <div id="output" class="black">
   
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

So, what am I doing wrong with `addEvenetListener` way above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to attach event using addEventListener, Do not use the "on" prefix. For example you should use like `keydown` instead of `OnKeyDown`.

```
 tweetTxt.addEventListener('keydown', textCounter, false);
 tweetTxt.addEventListener('keyup', textCounter, false);
 tweetTxt.addEventListener('change', textCounter, false);
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/hwmae1uf/)

**Note:** The addEventListener() method is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply change the event name on your code to this:

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var charCount = 10;
var tweetTxt = document.getElementById("tweettext");

function textCounter(){
  console.log("it works");
  var count = charCount - document.getElementById("tweettext").value.length;

  if(count < 0){
    output.classList.add("red");
    output.classList.remove("black");
    console.log("Less than zero");
  }else{
    output.classList.add("black");
    output.classList.remove("red");
  }
  output.innerHTML = count + " characters left";
}

tweetTxt.addEventListener('keydown', textCounter, false);
tweetTxt.addEventListener('keyup', textCounter, false);
tweetTxt.addEventListener('change', textCounter, false);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <textarea style="width: 100%" name="tweettext" id="tweettext" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="output" class="black">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, you added 3 events to one element, it will fires at least 3 times. When you type something, each character typed fires 2 events. Key down and key up. When you lost focus on textarea, the change event fires.

My suggestion is simple, use keyup or keydown event, along with additional conditions to check if user is typing valid characters (not pressing esc key, function keys etc.). If you do not need the count to be live, use change event.

There is another event you can attach to it to replace keyup, keydown.

```js
tweetTxt.addEventListener('input',function(e){
  // yourcode
});
```

Good luck.